# Are $\mathscr{V}$-modules uniquely (nicely) enrichable?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

$\require{AMScd}\newcommand{\V}{\mathscr{V}}\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}\newcommand{\hom}{\operatorname{hom}}\newcommand{\op}{{^\mathsf{op}}}$Fix a closed symmetric monoidal category $(\V;\otimes;\alpha,\lambda,\rho,\gamma)$, with hom objects written as $\underline{\V}$ and monoidal unit written as $\ast$. Re-defining the bifunctor $\underline{\V}$ if necessary, fix a choice of adjunction $\pi:\V(v\otimes w,z)\cong\V(v,\underline{\V}(w,z))$ which is natural in **all** variables.

Define a closed $\V$-module to be a category $\M$ equipped with bifunctors $\odot:\V\times\M\to\M,\hom:\M\op\times\M\to\V$, a choice of adjunction $\kappa:\M(v\odot m,n)\cong\V(v,\hom(m,n))$ which is natural in **all** variables and a natural associator and unitor $\alpha_\odot:v\odot(w\odot m)\cong(v\otimes w)\odot m,\lambda_\odot:\ast\odot m\cong m$ which make the following diagrams always commute: $$\begin{CD}u\odot(v\odot(w\odot m))@>1\odot\alpha_\odot>>u\odot((v\otimes w)\odot m)@>\alpha_\odot>>(u\otimes(v\otimes w))\odot m\\@V\alpha_\odot VV@.@VV\alpha\odot1 V\\(u\otimes v)\odot(w\odot m)@>>\alpha_\odot>((u\otimes v)\otimes w)\odot m@>>=>((u\otimes v)\otimes w)\odot m\end{CD}$$

$$\begin{CD}v\odot(\ast\odot m)@>\alpha_\odot>>(v\otimes\ast)\odot m\\@V1\odot\lambda_\odot VV@VV\rho\odot1V\\v\odot m@>>=>v\odot m\end{CD}$$

After some diagram chasing it's possible to show that there is a $\V$-category $\underline{\M}$ with the same objects as $\M$, with $\underline{\M}(m,n):=\hom(m,n)$ and an isomorphism of categories $\M\cong(\underline{\M})_0$ which is such that: $$\begin{CD}\M\op\times\M@>\cong>>(\underline{\M})_0\op\times(\underline{\M})_0\\@V\hom VV@VV\underline{\M}V\\\V@>>=>\V\end{CD}$$Commutes. That is, the isomorphism is "nice" and preserves the $\hom$ functor so that, really, we can happily abuse $\hom$ with $\underline{\M}$ (which is automatically defined differently from the $\V$-categorical structure).

Specifically, I should say the isomorphism of categories is given by keeping objects the same and mapping an arrow $f:m\to n$ in $\M$ to the arrow: $$\ast\overset{\eta}{\longrightarrow}\hom(m,\ast\odot m)\overset{\hom(1,f\lambda_\odot)}{\longrightarrow}\hom(m,n)=\underline{\M}(m,n)$$In $\V$ which represents, by definition, an arrow $m\to n$ in $(\underline{\M})_0$. Let's call this isomorphism $\tau$.

Question:

> Is there a *unique* way to define composition arrows $\underline{\M}(m,n)\otimes\underline{\M}(\ell,m)\to\underline{\M}(\ell,n)$ such that $(a)$ we get a genuine $\V$-category and $(b)$ $\tau$ is a genuine isomorphism of categories $(c)$ such that $\underline{\M}\circ(\tau\op\times\tau)=\hom$?

Note the only thing to check with regards to the isomorphism condition is that $\tau$ is functorial. It's equivalent to check that: $$\hom(1,f)\overset{?}{=}
\hom(\ell,m)\cong\ast\otimes\hom(\ell,m)\overset{\tau(f)\otimes1}{\longrightarrow}\hom(m,n)\otimes\hom(\ell,m)\overset{\diamond}{\longrightarrow}\hom(\ell,n)$$For all $f,\ell,m,n$, where $\diamond$ is the mysterious choice of composition arrow.

But given this, to check $(c)$ we only need to further check that the definition of $\hom(f,1)$ is preserved.

**Motivation**: there *is* a sense in which there is a unique way to define $\diamond$, so a positive answer to my question is plausible. However, in the positive result that I was able to obtain, we need to assert some more conditions on $\diamond$ to obtain the uniqueness. I will elaborate on this if asked.